# create a multi level Yii route

Tags: php, yii, url-routing, yii2-advanced-app, yii1.x

I am trying to make a url with regex in YII1.
I want to create the url for 'pagename/username'.

I tried like this :

```
'<pagename:([A-Za-z0-9-A-zÀ-ú]+)>/<i:w+>' => 'site/Profile',
```

but it is not working. Page is just reloading on itself

I want to show the new page when url become like 'pagename/username'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it work this way

```
'public/<pagename:([A-Za-z0-9-A-zÀ-ú]+)>/<i>' => 'site/Profile'
```

see that i had to put a "public" at the start to make it works, and remove the +w of i , my "site/profile" just is a print_r of the $_REQUEST;

```
Array ( [pagename] => pagename [i] => username )
```

EDIT: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56692124/11676981) of @rob06 is so much better, just remember put it first of the array "rules"

```
'rules'     => array(
     '<pagename:[\w-]+>/<i:\w+>'              => 'site/profile',
     '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'              => '<controller>/view',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'          => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
'<pagename:([A-Za-z0-9-A-zÀ-ú]+)>/<i:\w+>' => 'site/profile',
```

`w+` will handle handle usernames containing only "w" letters, you need to use `\w+` to handle any word.

Also `[A-Za-z0-9-A-zÀ-ú]+` looks suspicious - you should avoid non-ASCII letters in URLs, so `-A-zÀ-ú` should be unnecessary. I would recommend to use this rule:

```
'<pagename:[\w-]+>/<i:\w+>' => 'site/profile',
```